# Jquery AJAX Issue on Browser

Tags: jquery

My live site HTML code is at http://dev9.edisbest.com/PrinterManufacturers.htm?id=21

This works great in FireFox and Chrome and show `Status: Success`. Please can anyone tell me why it doesn't work on IE9.0 ?

The code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function hello(id){
var seriesurl = "http://t2json.tgoservices.com/818746/PrinterManufacturers/"+id+"/PrinterSeries"
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: seriesurl
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {      
      $('#status').html(textStatus);

    $.each(data.T2Json.PrinterSeries.Items, function(i,item) {
     $("#content1").html('<a class="manufacturer" id="'+item.Id+'" href="#">'+ item.Name + '</a></br>'); 
    });
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          $('#status').html(textStatus);    
          $('#content').html('(failed)');
        })
    }

$(document).ready( function() {

    function getParameter(param) {
        var val = document.URL;
        var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))
        var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
    }

    $('#time').html(new Date);
    $('#status').html('');
    $('#content').html('');
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: $('#xhr_url').val()
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {      
      $('#status').html(textStatus);

    $.each(data.T2Json.PrinterManufacturers.Items, function(i,item) {
     $("#content").append('<a class="manufacturer" id="'+item.Id+'" onclick="hello('+item.Id+');" href="#">'+ item.Name + '</a></br>'); 
    });
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      $('#status').html(textStatus);    
      $('#content').html('(failed)');
    })

     $('a .manufacturer').click(function(){
    });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id='xhr_url' style='width:600px;' type='text' value='http://t2json.tgoservices.com/818746/PrinterManufacturers'/>
<div id='content1'></div>
  <fieldset><legend>Time:</legend>
    <div id='time'></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset><legend>Status:</legend>  
    <div id='status'></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset><legend>Content:</legend>

    <div id='content'></div>

  </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: change `$('#time').html(new Date);` to `$('#time').html(new Date());`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss tried same error

Comment: error being thrown is "No Transport"

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aposof/3/edit

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks Mark for that url yes wondering why its throwing  No Transport error

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the first  `$.ajax({` is outside of `$(document).ready(`? It could be a race condition where in some cases jQuery is not loaded before the `$.ajax` attempts to run.

This is also a problem:

```
var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))
var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
```

That should either be:

```
var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param)),
    n=url.replace(param+"=","");
```

or

```
var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param));
var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
```

Comment: do you mean shall i put the function hello in $(document).ready ? I tried that but its the same error

Comment: Dude, I am pointing out that there are multiple problems with your code segment. It is possible that IE9 does not like one of them, but it is more likely that you will have to fix most of them. I helped you with two...

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with your code,

You are trying to make a cross domain JSON request and it appears as if you are trying to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to solve this problem.  However IE9 does not honor that header, instead it looks for XDomainRequest  See here: http://caniuse.com/#search=cors

Comment: Well its JsonP so there is no question of Cross Domain isnt it ?

Comment: I see no callback in the ajax response to show that it is jsonp but if you were using jsonp then yes this wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @user580950 Add the `dataType:"jsonp",` to force the jsonp to the ajax calls

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss when i tried to use JSONP it throws an error "Status:
parsererror"